# Perl - Reading the contents of a file in a structured manner

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

As the title states, I would like to read the contents of an already existing file that is dynamically generated by the Perl script. This file will more or less follow the same structure as seen in the example below. The only real difference would be the amount of data that follows.

```
Recv-Q Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port 
0      128                            *:111                           *:*     
0      128                            *:22                            *:*     
0      128                    127.0.0.1:631                           *:*     
0      128                            *:53944                         *:*     
0      100                    127.0.0.1:25                            *:*
```

The goal with reading this file will be to use the data and further filter the contents of it. An example would be to only list data that has the **Port:22** and present it to the end user, but this is beyond my question here.

What I would like to achieve is to read each header, e.g *Recv-Q*, *Send-Q*, *Local Address:Port* and *Peer Address:Port* as **keys** to a hash. The values thereafter will consist of the data residing under each header column. The goal is to be able to filter out certain columns using the header as a pointer to the values.

The code strucutre that I would wish to achieve would be a **hash** listing all the headers, and within each header there would lie an **array** contain all the column data.

I do not have any code examples of how I would go about to resolve this issue but I am very appreciative of any help on the matter.

Comment: I think the reason why there are no answers is the last sentence. Try something, and you may get help.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there are never any whitespace characters inside any of the fields you can just use `split`

This program uses a regex to do a very similar thing but divides the lines into six fields instead of four — keeping the port numbers separate from the addresses. It should at least get you started

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

<DATA>; # Lose header line

my @data;
while ( <DATA> ) {
  push @data, [ /[^\s:]+/g ];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;

__DATA__
Recv-Q Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port 
0      128                            *:111                           *:*     
0      128                            *:22                            *:*     
0      128                    127.0.0.1:631                           *:*     
0      128                            *:53944                         *:*     
0      100                    127.0.0.1:25                            *:*
```

**output**

```
[
  [0, 128, "*", 111, "*", "*"],
  [0, 128, "*", 22, "*", "*"],
  [0, 128, "127.0.0.1", 631, "*", "*"],
  [0, 128, "*", 53944, "*", "*"],
  [0, 100, "127.0.0.1", 25, "*", "*"],
]
```